# How do I get an auto-scrolling text display on .NET forms - e.g. for credits

Tags: .net, winforms, scroll, textbox

Need to show a credits screen where I want to acknowledge the many contributors to my application.

Want it to be an automatically scrolling box, much like the credits roll at the end of the film.

Answer (score 3):

A easy-to-use snippet would be to make a multiline textbox. With a timer you may insert line after line and scroll to the end after that:

```
textbox1.SelectionStart = textbox1.Text.Length;
textbox1.ScrollToCaret();
textbox1.Refresh();
```

Not the best method but it's simple and working. There are also some free controls available for exactly this auto-scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty method would be to use a Panel with a long list of Label controls on it that list out the various people and contributions. Then you need to set the Panel to be AutoScroll so that it has a vertical scrollbar because the list of labels goes past the bottom of the displayed Panel. Then add a time that updates the AutoScrollOffset by 1 vertical pixel each timer tick. When you get to the bottom you reset the offset to 0 and carry on. The only downside is the vertical scrollbar showing.

Answer (score 0):

Embed a WebBrowser control, and use a [technique like this](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-22_11-5076826.html) to do some javascript scrolling of the HTML content of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a .NET form you can just flick to the HTML view and use the marquee html element:

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_MARQUEE.html

To be honest it's not great and I wouldn't use it for a commercial job since it can come across as a bit tacky - mainly because it's been overused on so many bad sites in the past. However, it might just be a quick solution to your problem.

Another option is to use some of the features of the Scriptaculous JavaScript library:

http://script.aculo.us/

It has many functions for moving text around and is much more powerful.